# How to check if a user has a specific role in Meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, roles

I want to manage the users of my Meteor app and in order to do that I'll need to know their current roles.  I have a page setup that is only accessible to admin users and that page is subscribed to the users collection.

In my template for this page I have the following:

```
{{#each user}}
  <p>
    <a href="/@{{username}}">{{username}}</a>
    {{#if isInRole 'admin'}} Admin{{/if}}
  </p>  
{{/each}}
```

Unfortunately this leaves me with a problem where the logged in user's (which is an admin) role is what is compared in the `{{#if isInRole 'admin'}}` block.  This results in all the users having admin status (which is not the case).

How do I check if a user that is displayed from the `each` block is in a specific role?

Edit Note:  I am using the alanning/meteor-roles package

There is a list of all the users in the database, and I want to see their admin status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the following solution for anyone who runs into this issue in future.

JavaScript:

```
Template.registerHelper('isUserInRole', function(userId, role) {
  return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, role);
});
```

Template:

```
<p>
  Roles: {{#if isUserInRole _id 'webmaster'}}Webmaster {{/if}}
  {{#if isUserInRole _id 'admin'}}Admin {{/if}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own role checking functions like so:

```
isAdmin = function(){
  var loggedInUser = Meteor.user();
  var result = false;
  if(loggedInUser){
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['Admin'])){
      result = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

So save this in `./lib/roles.js` for example.

You will need to install the [alanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) package to use this.

Comment: I'm not trying to check if the logged in user is an admin, I have a list of all the users in the users collection and I want to see whether they are admins or not.

Comment: Precisely, so just render your list based on isAdmin === true.

Comment: Is there a way to put this function in my template helpers?  Because I've tried to implement it and it's not working.

Comment: Sure, 1 sec, currently replying on mobile. Will update my answer on a moment :-)